# Parents name change UK standard visitor visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I'm in the UK on an FLR-M visa, and I'm planning to invite and sponsor my parents from India on a visitor visa, My parents have changed their names recently(last 2 years). They have made their passport recently with the new name and all the documents have their new name.

All my documents contain their old names and I filled out their old name in my FLR-M visa application as well. Will the ECO check my FLR-M application as well?
Now, while applying for the visitor visa for my parents will it cause any problems?

Please help.

Comment: What documentation can your parents provide to evidence the legal process leading to the name change and issue of new passports?

Comment: @Willeke The question asks about applying for a UK visitor visa for the asker's parents. How is this off-topic on Travel?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, when the question was posted before, (same name for user, different account) I asked whether it was for short term visa or for long term visa and got the answer that it is for long term visa, so the question got migrated to Expats. Long term visa do not belong on Travel. (Some people decided a long time ago to have two separate sites, so this is a result.)

Comment: @Willeke Because the title contained "standard visitor visa" and the text said "visitor visa," I think the OP misunderstood your question, and answered as though you'd asked about the OP's status, which is indeed long-term, not his parents' hoped-for status.

Comment: Re-opened. I agree with your reasoning.

Answer (score 3):

It's a very safe bet that a change in parents' names from your earlier documents to your not-yet-filed new documents will be noticed by UKVI — visa examiners are always on the lookout for inconsistencies and changes. If you do not satisfactorily explain why the names are different, and how the names were changed, your new application will be denied.

You should, therefore, explain in your new application how the name change came about. Document the change if you can do so. For example, if your parents' names were changed in an Indian court or governmental administrative proceeding, obtain a certified copy of the Order Changing Name (for both of your parents) and include these documents in your application. I would also include copies of the data pages of their old names/superseded passports.